# Using PyPy with poetry

Tags: pypy, python-poetry

How one can use PyPy (preferably `pypy3`) instead of standard python with `poetry`?

That is, what should be stored in `pyproject.toml`?
Are other changes necessary as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out it is as easy as installing `pypy3` (for OS X: `brew install pypy3`) and typing the following in the project directory:

```
poetry env use /usr/local/bin/pypy3
```

given that PyPy lays in `/usr/local/bin/pypy3`.

Resolving all the dependencies for the new environment might be more tricky, but that's for the different questions.

Comment: I ended up using `poetry env use $(which pypy3)`, which is more robust to changes of environments. (My use-case is building a CI pipeline)